# Go Ex Theme Error message

Tags: javascript, android, error-handling, themes, launcher

So I made a theme for go launcher ex and it works fine on emulation and on my device when installed directly but when its installed from the app store it doesnt even open. In Go Ex theme setter it shows up as "loading" and can't be used. I was just wondering if anyone knew how to fix this problem. The error message below is from the google developer console:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver
>   com.gau.go.launcherex.theme.MLP.FIM.LulzDogApps.ComponentControlReceiver:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.gau.go.launcherex.theme.MLP.FIM.LulzDogApps.ComponentControlReceiver
>   in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app-private/com.gau.go.launcherex.theme.MLP.FIM.LulzDogApps-2.apk]at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1777)at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:985)at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.gau.go.launcherex.theme.MLP.FIM.LulzDogApps.ComponentControlReceiver
>   in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app-private/com.gau.go.launcherex.theme.MLP.FIM.LulzDogApps-2.apk]at
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1768)